# How do I send a "secure email"?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send an email to someone when they forget their password to their account but every time I try it says "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. How do I fix this?

```
            mailLogin = new NetworkCredential(Email, Password);
            client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = mailLogin;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(Email, Name, Encoding.UTF8) };
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email));
            msg.Subject = "Subject";
            msg.Body = "Message";
            msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
            string userstate = "Sending...";
            client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set EnableSsl to true.

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Then you must login to your google account and allow it to run less secure app (set to ON)

Comment: I have tried both and they dont work so I just left it as false

Comment: I have updated my answer.  You need to change some permissions in your google account.

Comment: I cant turn on allow less secure app because I dont have the right type of gmail account or something